# I want to get some data using hand tracking feature of head mounted display (HMD) how can I do it

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

What I want to do using Oculus quest pro or HTC VIVE is I want to calculate the depth and rhythm of my hand by using the hand tracking feature of these two devices.Also, I want to ask whether it is easier to do it in Augmented Reality or Virtual Reality.I've never done programming on augmented reality and virtual reality before, how should I handle this? Is there a course you can recommend?